# Mapbox setPaintProperty for circle-radius is not updating layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox circle layer and I need to change the radius of the circle but the setPaintProperty method doesn't seem to work.  The layer displays initially:

```
map.addLayer({
        "id": "circleCurrentGpsCircle",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "source_circleCurrentGpsCircle",
        "paint": {
          "circle-radius": {
            stops: [
              [0, 0],
              [22, metersToPixelsAtMaxZoom(gpsAccuracyWidth, currentLatitude)]
            ],
            base: 2
          },
          "circle-color": self.props.senData.gpsCircleShading ? "#FFFF00" : "transparent",
          "circle-opacity": 0.3,
          "circle-stroke-width": 3,
          "circle-stroke-color": "#FFFF00"
        }
      });
```

I then call the following to change the radius of the circle:

```
var radiusData = {
        stops: [
          [0, 0],
          [22, metersToPixelsAtMaxZoom(gpsAccuracyWidth, currentLatitude)]
        ],
        base: 2
      };
      this.map.getLayer('circleCurrentGpsCircle').setPaintProperty('circle-radius', radiusData);
```

The circle doesn't change though.  I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: Are you setting the `circle-radius` value to exactly what it already is? Are you certain `gpsAccuracyWidth` and `currentLatitude` have changed when you're calling the update?

Comment: The values are definitely changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, one calls `setPaintProperty` on the `map` object itself, not on a layer:

`this.map.setPaintProperty('circleCurrentGpsCircle', 'circle-radius', radiusData);`

I've never noticed the `setPaintProperty()` method on the returned layer object, but in my brief testing, it doesn't seem to work for me either.

(Actually with a bit of further testing, it seems that values set through that function do get recorded somewhere, and when you later call `map.setPaintProperty()`, all those values now get displayed. But this doesn't help you - just change the line to what I provided above.)